# Create Unit Tests context menu option missing in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

The 'Create Unit Test' context menu option seems to be missing from my copy of VS2017.

I know there was a bit of history where it was removed and [then re-added in VS2015](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/03/06/creating-unit-test-method-stubs-with-create-unit-tests/) after [much outcry](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2748862-add-create-unit-tests-menu-option-back), but as far as I can tell from [the Microsoft documentation for VS2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/developer-testing/getting-started/create-unit-tests-menu) it should be there now?

The solution I'm working on contains an ASP.NET Web API 2 app, a C# Class Library and a couple of test projects, all targeting .NET Framework 4.5.1. (I'm aware that this option shouldn't be there for .Net Core or .Net Standard projects (as discussed at length [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876897/where-is-create-unit-test-in-vs-2017?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

I've tried right clicking the class name and method name in the code window, the class name tab and the class file in solution explorer all to no avail.

Edit:
The "Testing tools core features" is already installed in my copy of VS:

[image]

Edit 2:
I can confirm this is now fixed in the latest versions of VS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This appears to be a known issue as stated here:

> Visual Studio Team ♦♦ · 6 days ago 0 (March 17, 2017)
>
> Thank you for your feedback! We have fixed the problem and the bug fix
>   will be included in an next update release. Thank you for helping us
>   build a better Visual Studio!

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24835/create-unit-tests-missing-when-right-click-in-meth.html

Edit: I can confirm this is now fixed (for projects targeting the full .NET framework) in the latest versions of VS.

NB: This is still not expected to be working for .NET Core projects [as per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876897/where-is-create-unit-test-in-vs-2017?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: More than a year later and I'm experiencing the same issue, so either they never fixed it or there was a regression.  I'm running VS 2017 15.8 (latest), C#, project is a .NET Core 2.1 DLL.  I really wish they'd fix this.

Answer (score 8):

Open "Visual Studio Installer" and modify your Visual Studio 2017 edition.

Selecting the *Individual Components* tab, make sure that under *Debugging and testing* that **Testing tools core features** is checked and installed.

Comment: I had high hopes for this, but it turns out that's already enabled on my version.

Comment: Same problem here (VS Pro 2017).

Comment: This worked, but had to restart the computer (not just VS) for it to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

**Make sure that your SQL Server Database Project compiles successfully** *before* looking at the SQL Server Object Explorer and right-clicking for the "Create Unit Tests" menu item, otherwise that the menu item will be disabled.  Fix SQL from within the project's own scripts until the project compiles, then look again.

Comment: This solved my issue. I didn't have any errors, but a simple `Solution > Rebuild` did the trick. Thanks, I was tearing my hair out looking at extensions and installer components!

Answer (score 0):

Also important to point out the Debug and Test options in the vs installer are limited based on your version of Visual Studio (Professional vs Enterprise)

Intellitest is a feature of the Enterprise offering for example.