# Unit testing features missing for .NET Core in VS 2019 and Visual Studio Installer?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, mstest, visual-studio-2019

I just added a MSTest .NET Core unit test project to a solution in VS 2019 but there now don't appear to be any features for adding a new unit test file to that project.

#### Missing Add > Unit test... context menu option

Steps to reproduce missing context menu issue:

- In Visual Studio 2019, add a new 'MSTest Project (.NET Core)' project to an existing solution
- Right click on the name of the new test project in Solution Explorer
- See if the option for 'Add > Unit test...' is present?

That option, which was present in earlier versions of VS (and that's still present in VS2019 for full unit test projects targeting the full .NET framework projects) is missing for me:

[image: VS2019 Context menu without 'Add > Unit test...' option]

#### Missing unit test templates

Steps to reproduce missing unit test template issue:

- In Visual Studio 2019, add a new 'MSTest Project (.NET Core)' project to an existing solution
- Right click on the name of the new test project in Solution Explorer
- Select 'Add > New item...'
- See if there are any C# related testing options?

I'm not seeing any unit test templates whatsoever:
[image: Add New Item dialog filtered for test showing no results]

#### What I've tried

I thought the issue might be that I [hadn't got the unit testing workload installed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42975299/1879019) for VS2019, but looking at the 'Individual components' option in the Visual Studio Installer for VS2019 the option for 'Testing tools core features' seems to have disappeared too:

[image: VS2019 installer with no test options]

These are the same options for VS2017 for comparison:
[image: VS2017 installer showing Testing tools core features option]

I know that the 'Create Unit Test' context menu option [is not expected to be present in VS2019](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42876897/1879019) yet, but to my knowledge the normal unit testing functionality and templates should be there?

(PS: I appreciate I can just write unit tests from scratch, I'm just asking if the functionality in VS has changed)

Comment: This feature is still in development for .net core projects. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44692742/7225096

Comment: Thanks @Peska. I've actually already linked to that answer in my question (I wrote that answer in fact).  That's a slightly different issue, the Create Unit Test option is a context option in the project you want to test, where as I'm asking about context options in the test project itself.  The missing options I'm describing in the question above *were* present for .NET Core in VS2017.

Comment: @tomRedox could be that VS 2019 is in preview mode, thus some features are missing. I have some ReSharper + VS2019 compatibility issues. Hope those will be fixed before official release

Comment: Hi @OlegI, thanks for the answer, for info VS2019 got its official release a couple of weeks ago (April 2nd). You're right though, this is probably just still work in progress, I was hoping someone knows for sure.

Comment: Same situation for .Net framework