# Auto-generate unit tests in ASP.NET Core 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-core

NOTE: I asked this on SoftwareEngineering site, but someone replied to the "where does my tooling question go", and that link said to ask on Stackoverflow (at least that's how I interpreted the answer)"

I've had this in previous projects, but I don't see it in my new ASP.NET Core 1.1 project.

Previously, I could just right-click on a method or class and select "Create Unit Tests" or "Run/Create IntelliTest".

After some googling, it looks like first versions of VS2017 or ASP.NET Core didn't have this feature yet.

Has this been added yet? If so, which versions of ASP.NET Core and Visual Studio do I need?

I have VS 2017 15.3.5
ASP.NET Core 1.1

Thanks!

Comment: That's been removed since VS2012 already.

Comment: No, I'm talking about IntelliTest which was introduced in VS2015 Ultimate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate unit test cases in VS 2017 .net core project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760377/how-to-generate-unit-test-cases-in-vs-2017-net-core-project)

Answer (score 2):

You said that you are using VS 2017, but you didn't specify which edition. The IntelliTest feature is available in VS 2017 **Enterprise**. Check out [Generate unit tests for your code with IntelliTest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/generate-unit-tests-for-your-code-with-intellitest)

Availability and extensions
The Create IntelliTest and Run IntelliTest menu commands:

- Are available in only the Enterprise Edition of Visual Studio 2015
  and later.
- Support only C# code that targets the .NET Framework.
- Are extensible, and support emitting tests in MSTest, MSTest V2,
  NUnit, xUnit format.
- Do not support x64 configuration.

Also, read [Generating Unit Tests with IntelliTest using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017](https://almvm.azurewebsites.net/labs/tfs/intellitest/)